# Open a new tab on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I have a requirement in which i have to foloow the steps in following manner :-

1. I have to search for a particular record using some filters.
2. The matching records will be displayed in a grid on the same page under a tab.
3. Now when I click on the data in grid, a new tab is opened with the description of that record.

Can somebody tell me how can I achieve this all tab formation on runtime through javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Hitesh

Comment: When you say "tab", are you speaking of a browser tab, or a tab that is part of the document?

Answer (score 0):

Not in programmers control. It is a **customizable option in many browsers**. So, depending upon user's customization, when you try to programatically open it in a new window, it is up to the browser to open it in a **new window** or **new tab**

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question, you can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) to create tabs at runtime via Javascript.  You will find you get better answers if you spend a little longer formatting the question.  Right now it feels like you're looking for an entire system.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code for opening new window:
window.open( "somephpfile.php","","width:1300,height:800" );

Use the following code for opening new tab:
window.open( "somephpfile.php");